# Angular subscription triggers just on component load

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to send object from sender component to the receiver component via service. 
In sender component there is a click event which send object to the service;

```
 export class SenderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private shareDataService: ShareDataService){}

  myData: Object;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myData = {};
  }

  onClick() {
    this.myData = {
      name: "Robert",
      visible: true
    }
    this.shareDataService.dataVisibility(this.myData);
  }
}
```

with button on the UI side:

```
<button (click)="onClick()"> Get Data </button>
```

Communication between components is achieved using Behavior Subject in service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ShareDataService {

  changeDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});

  public dataUpdate$ = this.changeDataSource.asObservable();

  public dataVisibility = (dataInfo: Object) => {
    this.changeDataSource.next(dataInfo);
  }
}
```

Receiver component has subscription to the observable;

```
export class ReceiverComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private shareDataService: ShareDataService) { }

  receivedData;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.shareDataService.dataUpdate$.subscribe(success => {
      console.log(success)
      this.receivedData = success;
    })
  }
}
```

but it fires only once on the component load with empty object (which is actually expected behaviour because there wasn't click on the first load). After that every click on the button send data to service, but nothing comes on the component, as if the subscription has finished :/

What could be the problem?

Comment: You're probably providing the service again in one of your components decorators. Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In another class the same service is provided using injector. Can that make a problem?

Comment: I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvkymt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsender%2Fsender.component.ts) based on code provided here. It works as expected.

Comment: @corry that is exactly the problem, the components have different instances of the service.

Comment: @AJT_82 Is there some example of using service in class (not component) and component? In my case object is sent from class (js project) to the angular component (angular project).

Comment: @robert thank you for the stackblitz, in the app, sender is TS class in other project which comunicates to the angular component via service which is injected in TS class and in angular project as well so it isn't easy to reproduce

Comment: @corry If you have to create the service outside of angular for your JS class that is not in angular then you will need to provide that non-angular instance instead of creating a new service instance.  Use something like the constant recipe here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#!

Comment: @Pace Is there some alternative for the constant recipe in angular 2?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, didn't realize that was an Angular 1 doc. The Angular 2 version would be a `useValue` provider https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#value-providers